# coxph: Loglik converged before variable

Tags: r, cox-model

I get this warning when applying a cox test to a small dataset `Warning message:In fitter(X, Y, stats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,:Loglik converged before variable  1 ; beta may be infinite.`

Both cohorts (groups) have ocurring events, so I understand the warning is not related to the absence of event at any of the two groups. Might it be related to the low sample size?

Code:

```
summary(coxph(Surv(OS, exitus) ~ group, data = xx`))
```

Input data:

```
   age sex   PFS    OS exitus change_diff group
    70   2  6.64 34.30      1       48.69     2
    74   1  6.54 29.04      1       43.96     2
    57   2 12.22 80.53      0       39.35     2
    60   1  8.67 52.99      0       37.41     2
    72   1  5.52 21.29      0        0.62     1
    68   1  1.22  6.11      1       -4.56     1
    70   1  1.28 15.67      1       -9.80     1
    75   1  2.07  6.18      1      -13.77     1
```

I've checked that there is no absence of events in any group

```
xtabs( ~ exitus+group, data=pats.df)
      group
exitus 1 2
     0 1 2
     1 3 2
```

Thanks

Comment: See the answer provided by IRTFM in 2013: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369314/r-coxph-warning-loglik-converged-before-variable